# Scala: How to mask the first N characters of a string

Tags: scala

Given a string that represents a credit card number...

```
val creditCardNo = "1111222233334444"
```

... how do I mask the first 12 characters with `*`?

```
val maskedCreditCardNo = "************4444"
```

Comment: It's a shame that som-snytt didn't make his `patch` comment an answer, since that's a much more idiomatic solution than the regular expression (which doesn't even solve the problem as stated in the title).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace all digit symbols unless 4 characters remain:

```
creditCardNo.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*")
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use `drop` or `substring` on the original number, and prepend the right number of "*":

```
"*" * 12 + (creditCardNo drop 12)
```

Comment: Idiomatically, `ns.patch(0, "*" * 12, 12)`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach where you can modify character values for each position, in this case those before position `12`,

```
creditCardNo.zipWithIndex.map (c => if (c._2 < 12) '*' else c._1 ).mkString
```

Note that despite the ability to change each position individually, this is not the most efficient way to manipulate strings.